# Pandas Chanining: Are there pefromance benefits?

Tags: pandas, chaining

Is chaining simply for readability or does it offer performance benefits, eg. less memory use due to not saving intermediate object?

Comment: hmmm, it depends. In my opinion readibility is main reason. E.g. `df.assign(x = 1)` vs `df['x'] = 1` is faster second option a bit.